# Does high log-likelihood imply high R^2

Tags: modeling, maximum-likelihood, r-squared

Does a high LL value imply that the model has a high $R^2$? I'm a very beginner to statistics so please excuse my naivete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, since for linear regression log likelihood is a sum of squared residuals plus some other terms, log likelihood is scale dependent. So for the same model multiplying the regressors by some constant will change log likelihood but R squared will remain the same.

Comment: to add to mpiktas LL can be more than 1 but Rsquared cant be greater than 1.

Comment: It would be more useful to construe "high likelihood" as meaning high *relative to a saturated model,* because that's the spirit in which the question was asked and it leads to a much more informative analysis.

Answer (score 3):

If all your models have normally distributed errors and are fit to exactly the same data, then there is a straightforward, increasing relationship between likelihood and R^2, since they're both ultimately about the sum of squared errors. But in general, no, you can't look at a pair of log likelihood values and assume much of anything about overall goodness of fit.

The clearest case of this is when you have models fit to two different data sets. The likelihood of getting exactly two heads and one tail from a fair coin after three flips is a lot higher than the likelihood of getting exactly four heads and two tails after six flips, even though the fit is equally good.